# Can I add a variable value in mySQL query to table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database in which I have three fields: `Field_1`, `Field_2`, `Field3`.

`Field_1` is auto-incremented integer.
`Field_2` will be a string value provided by the user.
`Field_3` should be a concatenation of `Field_2` and `Field_1`.

Example: `(1, Dog, Dog1)` should be added to my table without me providing the `"Dog1"` input.

How to do this? I want to make `Field_3` my primary key. I have tried to look for solutions online, but to no use. Sorry, if this is a very easy question.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: You cannot make field3 your primary key - if there is an auto_increment column then it has to be the primary key or the first node of a compound primary key..

Answer (score -1):

How is your values being provided?
If you are having an insert command you could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (Field_2, Field_3) VALUES (value2, CONCAT(value2, (SELECT MAX(Field_1) FROM table) +1 ))
```

I am not 100% for the +1 increase you need to check if that works or if you need to do a set before. (dont have an SQL server available right now to check it for you))